# HashBasedTable Table<String,String,Double> HashMap<String,Double>

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

i have `HashMap<String,Double>hm1` and guava table `Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService`

### HashMap hm1

```
fatima |0.97
AT&T   |0.96
```

### Table employeeYearsOfService

```
 Google={Bill Smith=1.75, Stacy Lerner=11.5}, 
 Microsoft={Bill Smith=13.2,Stacy Lerner=3.5}, 
 AT&T={Bill Smith=2.0, Stacy Lerner=1.4},
 fatima={Bill Smith=1.0, Stacy Lerner=2.0}
```

### Table reseults

```
fatima={Bill Smith=1.0, Stacy Lerner=2.0}
AT&T={Bill Smith=2.0, Stacy Lerner=1.4}
```

and i want this result by create a new table `Table<String, String, Double> results = HashBasedTable.create()` contains a row of `employeeYearsOfService`
who have a same key with `HashMap hm1` (this is my question)

this picture for mor understand
 [image: picture]

### My Code

**Table guava**

```
    Table<String, String, Double> employeeYearsOfService = 
    HashBasedTable.create();

    employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Stacy Lerner", 1.4);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Microsoft", "Stacy Lerner", 3.5);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Microsoft", "Bill Smith", 13.2);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Google", "Stacy Lerner", 11.5);

    employeeYearsOfService.put("AT&T", "Bill Smith", 2.0);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("Google", "Bill Smith", 1.75);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("fatima", "Bill Smith", 1.0);
    employeeYearsOfService.put("fatima", "Stacy Lerner", 2.0);
```

**hashmap hm1**

```
HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    HashMap<String, Double> hm1 = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    System.out.println(employeeYearsOfService);
    for (String key : employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet()) {

        for (Entry<String, Double> employee : 
        employeeYearsOfService.row(key).entrySet()) {
            sum += employee.getValue() * operatCible.get(k);
            sum2 += employee.getValue() * employee.getValue();
            vect1 += operatCible.get(k) * operatCible.get(k);
            Result = (sum / (sqrt(sum2) * sqrt(vect1)));
            k++;

        }

        hm.put(key, Result);

        k = 0;
        sum = 0.0;
        sum2 = 0.0;
        vect1 = 0.0;
        Result = 0.0;

    }
    System.out.println(hm);
    Set<Entry<String, Double>> set = hm.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Double>>
     (set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> o1,
                Map.Entry<String, Double> o2) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("le K nn");
    for (Entry<String, Double> entry : list.subList(0, 2)) {
        hm1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());


    }
```

**loop for new Table**

```
Table<String, String, Double> results = HashBasedTable.create();
    System.out.println(hm1);
    for (Entry<String, Double> entry : list) {
       if(entry.getKey().equals(employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet())){
           results.put(employeeYearsOfService.row(entry.getKey())));
           // how i do it
       }


    }
```

thank you very much

Comment: any suggestions!!

Comment: So you want the intersection of the table with the hashmap? i.e. return a table which only has the rows with a key that matches the key of the map

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes!!

Comment: Do you need to create a new table or are you OK deleting the elements that are not in the map from the original table?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes i think about deleting from original table,is very useful

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner but how i do that??

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would consist of removing the elements you don't want from the table:

```
employeeYearsOfService.rowKeySet()
    .removeIf(key -> !hm1.containsKey(key));
```

Here I'm using the [`Table.rowKeySet` method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#rowKeySet--) to get the set of row keys from the table. This set is *bounded* to the original table, meaning that when an element is removed from this set, an entire row (with the same key) will be removed from the table. And this is what I'm doing with the [`Collection.removeIf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), whose predicate returns `true` if the key is not present in the `hm1` map.

Comment: @fatoma You're most welcome. Please see my updated answer for a simpler version.